# Meaning of "round" in the given context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Please see the following sentence:

> It is not much difficult to bend a free kick **round** a wall of
>   defenders.

I am not sure which of the following meanings of the word "round" fits here:

> adv.
>   1. In a circular progression or movement; around.
>   2. With revolutions: wheels moving round.
>   3. To a specific place or person: called round for the pastor; sent round for the veterinarian.
>
> prep.
>   1. Around.
>   2. From the beginning to the end of; throughout: a plant that grows round the year.

Comment: In my opinion, it's "perp. 1. Around".

Comment: Can you say whether the usage in your example is as an adverb or a preposition? Also is there a source for your example, or you wrote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the use of

> **round**

instead of

> **around**

is more a British usage.

> You have your shirt the wrong way **round** *(BrE)*
>   You have your shirt the wrong way **around** *(AmE)*

So, the meaning of your example sentence is

> It is not much difficult to bend a free kick *around* a wall of defenders.